# Laravel 5.2 Post form to external URL on submit

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using a third party payment service.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="https://exampledomain.com/postpayment.php">
<input type="hidden" name="CRESecureID" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="trans_type" value=" 2"/>
<input type="hidden" name="content_template_url" value="https://example.com/enterpaymentdetails.html"/>
<input type="hidden" name="allowed_types" value=" 3"/>
<input type="hidden" name="total_amt" value="$payment->amount"/>
<input type="hidden" name="collect_total_amt" value="$payment->total"/>
<input type="hidden" name="sess_id" value="e91dd8af53j35k072s0bubjtn7"/>
<input type="hidden" name="sess_name" value="session"/>
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="https://example.com/return.html"/>

<p><label> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/> </label></p>
```

How can I correctly send these variables to an external URL? Should I do it in the controller? An example would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by external URL ? is it your own domain or posting this to some one else URL ?

Comment: @Qazi It will be going to the payment service I use. Not my own domain.

Answer (score 5):

Best method to implement this is:

Post form data to one of your own URL, then post this data to the required external URL using Guzzle client or curl request.

This approach will help you to track the response from the external URL and manipulate or use it if required.

Hope this helps.

Comment: By "track the response" do you mean that I can get the response variables they send back.  For example I will get a reponse back like `https://example.com/return.html?order_id=6&code=000&msg=Success&error=000ApprovalCode=012345` I will be able to get the `Success` and `ApprovalCode` parameters and use them to update a table or pass them to a controller?

Comment: @michealb Yes, this is exactly what I want to say. You can easily use the response that they will send as confirmation.

Comment: In case of PayU Money and other similar gateways, you'll have to post data directly from the view.

Comment: @ManilBetra Sorry one last question. What do you mean by "post data to your own URL"? Do you have any examples?

Comment: Own URL means create a route in your own app on which this form posts the data and you can catch this in your own controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it on controller, a good approach will be to get these variables on controller, pass them to repository/service layer, perform all the validation checks and once everything is good, send them via `CURL POST`.

You can use `Request` to validate the form fields. Validate, process and send.

Here is the code to send data via CURL post

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "URL_OF_API");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFieldsArray);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding double forward-slash in your form action

E.g. `<form action="{{'//newsite.com/whatever'}}" >`

That is all.